# furnace exhaust - move for renovation

Tags: hvac, furnace, exhaust-vent

We are in the US. We have a 95% efficient furnace that exhausts to the house in a straight line from the furnace to the wall. We are building an extension to the house and the exhaust will now be a room. So two questions:

1. Can we move the exhaust vent ourselves? (We are quite handy)?
2. Does the exhaust need to go in a straight line? Can it have a 90degree bend?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check the spec sheet on that particular furnace for the size of the piping needed for the total length of piping including all fitting. Use the conversion sheet to turn all fittings into equivalent lengths of pipe, total all the pipe lengths, and choose the size of piping needed.

Comment: Thank you. So I will assume everything is on the spec sheet, which of course will be on the web!

Comment: I would add, if you can’t find what you need or don’t understand it call the manufacturer and they can help advise you.